# Injecting objects, which extends from a parent class in Slim

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim

I'm playing around with Slim PHP framework and stumbled upon a situation I cannot work out.

First, I'll explain the basic setup:

Using [slim-skeleton](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton), I have a dependencies.php file, where the DIC is set up. It's the default slim-skeleton's setup with two more things:

```
$container['db'] = function ($c) {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', '********', '********');
};

$container['model.user'] = function ($c) {
    $db = $c['db'];
    return new Dash\Models\User($db);
};
```

So, as you can see, I have two new things registered in the DIC - A **PDO** object and a **User** object.

But passing a database object for each and every other model is a bit of a pain... I would like to be able to inject the PDO object to a parent class, called **Model**.

So the Model should look like this:

```
class Model
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

And the User model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function getById($id)
    {
        $this->db->... // I have access to the database object (PDO) from the parent class.
    }
}
```

The thing is that I cannot have a parent object, because the slim's container returns a new instance of **User** and does not instantiate the parent **Model** class.

Any ideas on how to achieve inheritance, using Slim's container in a clean and usable way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instantiating a child class in your case still will need the base class' constructor. The inheritance does not work this way. You do extend classes, not already created objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how inheritance works. `User` **is** an instance of `Model`. So when you do `new User($c['db'])`, it'll work fine.

Comment: Ahm, well, I need a break. You're totally right. Thanks!